# curl Apache setup access python script

Tags: python, apache, curl

I have 2 boxes. One with setup and another where I have recently setup-ed.

The box in which setup is already available I see my program output via below curl command:

```
curl "http://setup.com/~prakash_prasad/tools/runreport.py"

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<charts><showChart>True</showChart><transaction>
 Start;100;90;95
</transaction><transactionday>
 Start;20040;34460;45050
</transactionday></charts>
```

where runreport.py is a python script that hits DB, gets data and prints it in formatted XML format.

In the another box I recently installed / config Apache 2.4.1 and get my project first page when I hit to the box via a browser. But the same backend script is having issues. I tried testing the output via same curl in the new dev setup box:

```
curl "http://mybox.com:8181/runreport.py"

#!/usrbin/python

import cgi
import MySQLdb
from xml.dom.minidom import Document

print "Content-type: text/xml"
print

...................
```

Surprisingly I get the runreport.py content dump as against the program output dump as in setup box? What's Apache config should I enable to dump output same as setup box?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is almost certainly a configuration issue rather than a problem with your code. What version of Linux(?) are you running on the two boxes? What version of Python? What version of Apache is on the first server?

Comment: This isn't really a programming problem so you might get better responses on ServerFault.com..

Comment: What happens if you try to run that script locally on box 2?

Comment: They are the same in both boxes - Apache 2.4.1, Red Hat Linux, Python 2.6

Comment: When I run locally - python runreport.py I get Content-type: text/xml <?xml version="1.0"?> ... as desired or like setup box

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me as though Apache on the second box doesn't understand that your python script should be executed instead of being served up as a file for download.

Comment: Please let me know what Apache config I need to add / modify?

Comment: Are you sure you have mod_python (or something along those lines) to tell apache how to handle .py files installed on box 2? https://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=calling+python+code+from+apache+2

Comment: I am trying to build mod_python 3.3.1 from http://www.modpython.org/ but make error. Which version of mod_python can be taken as stable and perfect for Apache 2.x release?

Comment: I now have the mod_wsgi installed - Apache/2.4.1 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.1 configured -- resuming normal operations [apache logs] but a sample program still dumps the code not the output : #!/usr/local/bin/python2.7
print "Content-type: text/html"
print
print "Hello, World."

Comment: httpd: Syntax error on line 148 of bin/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load bin/modules/mod_python.so into server: bin/modules/mod_python.so: undefined symbol: ap_requires